# Dynamic Color-Thief / Get dominant color

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, color-thief

I have a very special problem with color-thief. I'm trying to load some data from my datatable containing a realtive path to a image stored on the same domain.
There are about 20 links where I have to grab the dominant color and push it to an array.

My problem is now, that when i load my data (with AJAX) and I try to grab the color, the image is not loaded jet and i get a "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0."

So here is what i have tried so far:

**METHODE 1: GetColor**

```
// Create Objects for colorThief
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
var myImage = new Image();
var colors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i += 3) {
    labels.push(result[i]);                
    data.push(result[i + 1]);                      

    myImage.src = result[i + 2];
    var color = colorThief.getColor(myImage);
    colors.push("#" + rgbToHex(color[0]) + rgbToHex(color[1]) + rgbToHex(color[2]));
}
```

**METHODE 2: GetColorByUrl**

```
// Create Objects for colorThief
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
var colors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i += 3) {
    labels.push(result[i]);                
    data.push(result[i + 1]);                      

    //Also tried with a absolute path, not changing anything
    var color = colorThief.getColorFromUrl(result[i + 2]);
    colors.push("#" + rgbToHex(color[0]) + rgbToHex(color[1]) + rgbToHex(color[2]));
}
```

**METHODE 3: Append Image to HTML**

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
var colors = [];
var content = "<div id='temp' style='display:none'>";

//Create options
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i += 3) {
    options += "<option value='" + result[i] + "'>" + result[i + 1] + "</option>";

    content += "<img src='" + result[i + 2] + "'>";
}

content += "</div>"

$("#contentRightTop").append(content);

var thisColor;
var theseColors = [];

$("#temp img").each(function () {
    thisColor = colorThief.getColor(this);
    theseColors.push(thisColor);
});

$("#temp").remove();
```

**METHODE 4: Object.onload**

```
// Create Objects for colorThief
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
var myImage = new Image;
var colors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i += 3) {
    labels.push(result[i]);                
    data.push(result[i + 1]);                      

    myImage.onload = function() {
        var color  = colorThief.getColor(myImage);
        colors.push("#" + rgbToHex(color[0]) + rgbToHex(color[1]) + rgbToHex(color[2]));
    }
    myImage.src = result[i + 2];
}
```

So how i told you, so far nothing really worked. I also tried to set absolute paths to my domain.

THE ONLY methode that worked, was a try catch, with repeating the whole for loop, what wasn't that nice.

So guys if you would have some ideas/inputs on how to solve this problem or also alternatives to color-thied (it's very heavy) would be great.

Mention, that i allready tried to combine/replace color-thief with this scipts:

- [ImagesLoaded - Very bugy in Google Chrome](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)
- [Colorify - Didn't manage to change the script to what i need](https://github.com/LukyVj/Colorify.js)
- [Dominant-Color - Has imagemagick dependencie, that i want to avoid]
- [Adaptive Background - Same as Colorify]
- [PrimaryColor - I have to give it a try again, think there was an error in my code]

(Only allowed to post 2 links^^)

Thanks so far
Martin

Comment: Give this a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391762/working-with-jquery-load-callbacks-and-images/10391824#10391824

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll give it it a try and let you know